# Qt XML Viewer? (Like Notepad++)

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have an `QDialog` that contains a `QTextBrowser`, this dialogs only feature is to display an XML document in the `QTextBrowser`. The `QDialog` takes a `std::string` as a parameter and then using `QXmlStreamReader` and `QXmlStreamWriter` it converts that string into a "pretty print" formatted xml string and then sets that string to the `QTextBrowser` on the UI.

This is all working fine but ideally i would like to be able to click on the open/close tags and have it do some clever highlighting, also be able to collapse and expand tags, essentially what im looking for is the same functionality as Notepad++ when in XML mode.

Im wondering if anyone knows of any Qt C++ compatible libraries that accomplish this or if there is anything in Qt itself that may have this functionality (although i have had a good look and cant find anything).

Note: This `QTextBrowser` is simply displaying the XML it is set to read only so no editing it required i simply need this functionality for viewing only (if that makes a difference)

Any suggestions welcomed cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at [QScintilla](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/qscintilla/intro) which should be quite powerful, but its only a port to Qt.

Or for example [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this page for an example of how to use [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsyntaxhighlighter.html) to display a xml:
http://www.yasinuludag.com/blog/?p=49

Here is a re implementation of QSyntaxHighlighter that highlights xmls almost like notepad++ does

```
class XMLHighlighter : public QSyntaxHighlighter
{
public:
    XMLHighlighter(QTextDocument *parent) : QSyntaxHighlighter(parent) {
        HighlightingRule rule;

        // >text<
        QTextCharFormat xmlValueElementFormat;
        xmlValueElementFormat.setForeground(Qt::black);
        xmlValueElementFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
        rule.pattern = QRegExp(">[^\n]*<");
        rule.format = xmlValueElementFormat;
        highlightingRules.append(rule);

        // keywords
        QTextCharFormat keywordFormat;
        keywordFormat.setForeground(Qt::blue);
        keywordFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
        QStringList keywords;
        keywords << "\\b?xml\\b" << "/>" << ">" << "<";
        foreach (const QString &keyword, keywords) {
            rule.pattern = QRegExp(keyword);
            rule.format = keywordFormat;
            highlightingRules.append(rule);
        }

        // <Text> </Text>
        QTextCharFormat xmlElementFormat;
        xmlElementFormat.setForeground(Qt::blue);
        rule.pattern = QRegExp("\\b[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=[\/>])");
        rule.format = xmlElementFormat;
        highlightingRules.append(rule);

        // < Text= >
        QTextCharFormat xmlAttributeFormat;
        xmlAttributeFormat.setForeground(Qt::red);
        rule.pattern = QRegExp("\\b[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?=\\=)");
        rule.format = xmlAttributeFormat;
        highlightingRules.append(rule);

        // <!-- Text -->
        QTextCharFormat singleLineCommentFormat;
        singleLineCommentFormat.setForeground(Qt::gray);
        rule.pattern = QRegExp("<!--[^\n]*-->");
        rule.format = singleLineCommentFormat;
        highlightingRules.append(rule);

        // = "Text"
        QColor valueColor(128, 0, 255);
        valueFormat.setForeground(valueColor);
        valueFormat.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
        valueStartExpression.setPattern("\"");
        valueEndExpression.setPattern("\"(?=[\s></])");
    }

    virtual ~XMLHighlighter() {
    }

private:
    struct HighlightingRule
    {
        QRegExp pattern;
        QTextCharFormat format;
    };
    QVector<HighlightingRule> highlightingRules;

    QTextCharFormat valueFormat;
    QRegExp valueStartExpression;
    QRegExp valueEndExpression;

    void highlightBlock(const QString & text)
    {
        //for every pattern
        foreach (const HighlightingRule &rule, highlightingRules)
        {
            QRegExp expression(rule.pattern);
            int index = expression.indexIn(text);

            while(index >= 0) {
                int length = expression.matchedLength();
                this->setFormat(index, length, rule.format);
                index = expression.indexIn(text, index + length);
            }
        }

        this->setCurrentBlockState(0);
        int startIndex = 0;

        if(this->previousBlockState() != 1)
            startIndex = valueStartExpression.indexIn(text);

        while(startIndex >= 0)
        {
            int endIndex = valueEndExpression.indexIn(text, startIndex);
            int commentLength;

            if (endIndex == -1) {
                this->setCurrentBlockState(1);
                commentLength = text.length() - startIndex;
            }
            else {
                commentLength = endIndex - startIndex + valueEndExpression.matchedLength();
            }

            this->setFormat(startIndex, commentLength, valueFormat);
            startIndex = valueStartExpression.indexIn(text, startIndex + commentLength);
        }
    }
};
```